# Insert Bullet Points in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, bullets

Is it possible to create a list within in a Cell using bullet points ?

I currently use ALT + Enter for a line break, but it would look better if I could too add bullet points.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going to have to 'fake it' since formatting in Excel is applied at the cell level and cannot go any lower.

The easiest way to fake bullet points in Windows is to hold down the ALT key and press 7 on the numeric keypad to insert a bullet character like this: •

After prepending each line with a bullet character and a space, you'll have something that looks like:

[image: Excel]

One caveat you'll see here is that you won't be able to have wrapped lines properly indented this way, but I hope that's good enough.

Note that copying bulleted text from Word into Excel produces the same result. Excel knows it cannot use Word's rich-text representation in this case and uses the plaintext representation, which includes fake bullet characters and additional spaces.

Comment: Alt 7 will do just fine for me, I had saw that on another forum, but it did not mention using the num keypad

Comment: Glad to clear up that mystery for you! And of course, there are many more alt-codes you can use. https://fsymbols.com/keyboard/windows/alt-codes/list/

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not directly answer the question, it does address the motivation. I have disciplined myself to consider using MS Word if all I am doing is structuring information in a table. I now only use Excel if I am going to use spreadsheet functions (i.e. numerical calculations or conditional logic).

My short answer to that OP is "use MS Word" because the example on the screen does not indicate any functional use of the spreadsheet.

If some sort of additional function is required, try a different way of laying out the information because the use of dot points that relate to some other function implies an inefficient organisation of data and may interfere with a future function or need.

In my experience, trying to make things look nice in Excel is too hard (column widths, limited formatting, lack of real line breaks, lack of indents and dots, poor header/footer controls etc.). Likewise, using Excel for calendaring  and timeline planning is simply using the wrong tool for the job and makes one's life harder (long term thinking, not short term thinking).